# Properly using parameterized Factory.Create() method using DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, mvp, factory-pattern

My factory is using method injection because I thought this was the best way to make it so far. Besides, I doubt it is a good thing after having to call on its `Create` method from within a dependent object.

The only way I might think of whilst continuing to use the parameterized factory `Create` method, is to inject the dependencies directly in the `MainPresenter` so that it may provide with the dependencies to the method, and I dislike it. It dislike it because it is not the `MainPresenter` that depends on the `ICustomerManagementView` and the `ICustomerDetailPresenterFactory`, it's its dependency. So I would feel like I'm sabotaging my own code by doing so.

**MainPresenter**

```
public class MainPresenter : Presenter<IMainView>, IMainViewUiHandler {
    public MainPresenter(IMainView view
        , ICustomerManagementPresenterFactory customerManagementFactory) 
        : base(view) {
        this.customerManagementPresenterFactory = customerManagementPresenterFactory;
    }

    public void ManageCustomers() {
        // The following line is causing trouble.
        // As you can see per the ICustomerManagementPresenterFactory code sample,
        // the Create() method takes two parameters: 
        //   1. ICustomerManagementView, and
        //   2. ICustomerDetailPresenterFactory 
        // Hence I have to provide the dependencies manually, I guess. Which is
        // something to avoid at any cost.            
        var customerManagementPresenter = customerManagementPresenterFactory.Create();
        customerManagementPresenter.ShowView();
    }
}
```

**ICustomerManagementPresenterFactory**

```
public interface ICustomerManagementPresenterFactory {
    // Here. Though I ask Ninject to inject my dependencies, I need to
    // provide values to the parameters when calling the method from within
    // the MainPresenter class. The compiler won't let me do otherwise! And
    // this makes sense!...
    [Inject]
    CustomerManagementPresenter Create(ICustomerManagementView view
                                     , ICustomerDetailPresenterFactory factory);
}
```

**IMainView**

```
public interface IMainView : IView, IHasUiHandler<IMainViewUiHandler> {
}
```

**IMainViewUiHandler**

```
public interface IMainViewUiHandler : IUiHandler {
    void ManageCustomers();
}
```

**IUiHandler**

```
public interface IUiHandler { 
}
```

**IHasUiHandler**

```
public interface IHasUiHandler<H> where H : IUiHandler {
    H Handler { set; }
}
```

**MainForm**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form, IMainView {
    public MainForm() { InitializeComponent(); }

    public IMainViewUiHandler Handler { private get { return handler; } set { setHandler(value); } }
}
```

**CompositionRoot**

```
public class CompositionRoot {
    private CompositionRoot() { }

    public static IKernel BuildObjectGraph() {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
        BindFactories(kernel);
        BindViews(kernel);
    }

    private static void BindFactories(IKernel kernel) {
        kernel.Bind(services => services
            .From(AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                .GetAssemblies()
                .Where(a => !a.FullName.Contains("Tests")))
            .SelectAllInterfaces()
            .EndingWith("Factory")
            .BindToFactory()
        );
    }

    private static void BindViews(IKernel kernel) {
        kernel.Bind(services => services
            .From(AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                .GetAssemblies()
                .Where(a => a.FullName.Contains("Windows")
                         && !a.FullName.Contains("Tests"))
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .EndingWith("Form")
            .BindSelection((type, baseType) => type
                .GetInterfaces()
                .Where(iface => iface.Name.EndsWith("View"))
            )
        );
    }
}
```

So I wonder, is it best to implement the `ICustomerManagementPresenterFactory` and bind the implementer with it within my `CompositionRoot`, so that I could provide those dependencies through constructor injection to the `Create` method which shall no longer take any arguments, or shall I make it otherwise?

What I like of writing a simple interface is that Ninject does it all for me to a factory, and no code is necessary to build an instance of the desired type. Besides, when the constructor of the class to be created uses constructor injection, it seems like it is impossible to have a simple factory interface bound as a factory, and one need to implement the factory interface by hand.

What did I get right/wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of fact you don't need to pass parameters to the factory `Create` method at all - except in case they are parameters which need to be passed "down" because they cannot be bound in the composition root (for example an input value). However, passing such parameters to constructors is usually a code smell. Mostly, it's a better idea to pass these parameters to methods instead of constructors (for example: `Adder.Add(5,3);`, not `new Adder(5, 3).ComputeResult();`.

Now consider the following example, which works perfectly fine:

```
public class Dependency1 { }

public interface IDependency2 { }
public class Dependency2 : IDependency2 { }

public interface IBar { }

public class Bar : IBar
{
    public Bar(Dependency1 d1, IDependency2 d2) { }
}

public interface IBarFactory 
{
    IBar Create();   
}


var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<IBarFactory>().ToFactory();
kernel.Bind<IBar>().To<Bar>();
kernel.Bind<Dependency1>().ToSelf();
kernel.Bind<IDependency2>().To<Dependency2>();

var factory = kernel.Get<IBarFactory>();
var bar = factory.Create();

bar.Should().BeOfType<Bar>();
```

even though `Bar` takes two constructor arguments, the generated `IBarFactory`'s `Create()` method does not specify so. No problem, ninject will resolve it automatically.

Now let me give you an example what `.ToFactory()` actually results in. Consider the factory:

```
public interface ISomeFactory
{
    ISomething Create(string parameter1);
}
```

Will result in (remark: it's realised by interceptors and not by weaving it, so the example is a simplificiation):

```
public class SomeFactory : ISomeFactory
{
    private readonly IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot;

    public SomeFactory(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
    {
        this.resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
    }

    public ISomething Create(string parameter1)
    {
        this.resolutionRoot.Get<ISomething>(new ConstructorArgument("parameter1", parameter1);
    }
}
```

The `ConstructorArgument` tells ninject to pass the value of `parameter1` to the ctor-parameter named "parameter".

All other parameters are resolved "as usual". If a constructor parameter cannot be resolved (neither passed as parameter nor bound) ninject will throw an exception stating that the parameter cannot be resolved.